# Show/Hide column in Power BI Table/Matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Is there any possibility to show or hide the column in **Table/Matrix** visual in Power BI report by user dynamically?

For Example, I have a table view with columns **COLUMN-1, COLUMN-2, COLUMN-3**. Now I may have filter drop down to list all the column headers, so based on user selection (Multiple selections) Table view should get adjusted to show column values.

Since Power BI was developed based on Excel, curious to know if we are having Hide/Show column based on any condition or available in visual by default (Maybe by right-clicking on column header then show/hide it).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following workaround:

- Create your page with the table showing both columns.
- Create a bookmark, uncheck "Data"
- Duplicate the page and remove the column you want to conditionally hide. Set the page as hidden.
- Create a bookmark, uncheck "Data"
- Add a button to the first page pointing to the 2nd bookmark
- Add a button to the second page pointing to the 1st bookmark
- Ensure your slicers are synced

The end user experience is they will feel like they are conditionally hiding and unhiding the column.

A bit crap and a lot of extra work but I have it working well in my implementation.

Comment: Good workaround. You can actually do this trick on the same page, i.e. duplicate the table and adjust each to show/hide relevant columns. Then have only the first table shown (use "Selection" view) - assign it to the 1st bookmark, and then have only the second table shown - assign it to the 2nd bookmark.

Comment: @Mike250: Appreciate your answer for this post.!

Comment: I suppose the "good" in "good workaround" depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  We have 8 columns that was want to show/hide in various, unpredictable combinations so we'd need 256 tables.  I'm really hoping in the 3 years since this answer was posted that Power BI has gotten better.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to hide columns in visual based on slicer selection, there is an idea about this issue, please vote it up.

https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19435267-conditional-visibility-of-a-visual-based-on-slicer

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did... But looking for if there are any other workaround

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in Power BI with preview feature "Field Parameter". Check the May 2022 update.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any documentation you have?